# How to display links in specific page

Tags: posts

I have following links in content.php and i want to display in specific page with condition. Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

- Home
- Director’s speech
- Projects
- Our Vision
- Volunteers
- Inquiry

Comment: I guess you cannot do that on wordpress.com. You will have to ask their support.

Comment: i am trying in localhost not in wordpress.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either [create a custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), or just add the code to your regular `page.php`:

```
if ( is_page( 'your-page-slug' ) )
{
    echo 'your links';
}
```